# Printing class name only once if same object is detected in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I used the following code for printing the class name, but I only want the class name once if the class name is already printed.
For example, if a person is detected by it, the class name `person` is printed in a loop.
I need to print the class name only if it is not detected previously.

```py
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
        ret,image_np=cap.read()
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
        boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
        scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
        a=[category_index.get(i) for i in classes[0]]
        x=a[0]
        y=x['name']
        print(y)
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
        cv2.imshow('object detection',cv2.resize(image_np,(800,600)))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          cv2.destroyAllWindows()
          break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a list object before while loop and append the class name based on the condition.

I have modified your code with conditions to print class name only once.

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    present = []
    while True:
        ret,image_np=cap.read()
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
        boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
        scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
        (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
        a=[category_index.get(i) for i in classes[0]]
        x=a[0]
        y=x['name']
        if y in present:
          pass
        else:
          present.append(y)
          print(y)
        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
        cv2.imshow('object detection',cv2.resize(image_np,(800,600)))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          cv2.destroyAllWindows()
          break
```

I hope this answers your question. Happy Learning!

Comment: @Prashast Yadav -  If you think I have answered your question, please accept it and upvote, Thank You.